# Argument is not assignable to type of my interface

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm fairly new to Typescript and I have an Angular project, where I have a simple interface:

```
IEmail {
   email_type:string,
   email_address:string
}
```

I  have a simple method that basically compares the value of two arrays and if it finds a value in one array equal to a value in the other array, it splices out that value.

The code I use to do this is:

```
        this.contact.shared.emails.map((val)=> {
          this.profile.emails.indexOf(val.email_address) < -1 ? this.emailArray.splice(val, 1) : '';
        });
```

Where 'val' is of type

My problem is that in the line:

```
 this.profile.emails.indexOf(val.email_address) < -1 ? this.emailArray.splice(val, 1) : '';
```

I get an error with: (val.email_address), because this value is a string parameter of the `<IEmail>` interface type.

So I get the error that

> 'Argument of type string is not assignable to parameter type of
>   IEmail'.

How do I resolve this???

By the way, I did notice that I can get rid of that error by changing the parameter types in my interface to 'any' vs 'string', but that brings up a new error, where the 'val' in this line:

```
this.emailArray.splice(val, 1)
```

generates the error: Argument of type 'IEmail' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.

Comment: Thanks, fateme, but that didn't work. Same error...

Comment: the second error is because of val is  ```'IEmail'``` type and ```splice()``` need ```number```.

Comment: Do it in two steps, get indexof first and splice that number

Answer (score 0):

Change it as follows, **[`Array.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)** takes an argument of number.

```
this.contact.shared.emails.map((val)=> {
     const ind = this.profile.emails.indexOf(val.email_address);
     this.profile.emails.indexOf(val.email_address) < -1 ? this.emailArray.splice(ind, 1) : '';
});
```

Comment: Hi Sajeetharan, your code seems to have resolved the type error, but for some reason the ind always returns as -1, though there are two email addresses in my test.

Comment: you need to check your array this.profile.emails or try using .includes method

Comment: I'm running console.logs on each line and can see that the same emails are in both arrays. How would I use the includes method to find the location of a duplicate email and splice it out?

Comment: Can you post what you see when you put console.log(JSON.stringify(this.profile.emails));

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
this.contact.shared.emails.map((val)=> {
let currentEmail:IEmail={};
for(let email of this.profile.emails){
    if(email.email_address === val.email_address){
        currentEmail = email;
        }
   }
this.profile.emails.indexOf(currentEmail) < -1 ? this.emailArray.splice(val, 1) : '';
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution:

```
          this.profile.emails = this.profile.emails.filter(e=>{
            return this.contact.shared.emails.find(e1 => e1.email_address===e.email_address) == null
          })
```